# Encryption on a cloud

Tags: mount, encryption, cloud, google-drive

What is the most convenient option up for now?

I tried `FUSE` + `encfs`, but it turns out to be extremely slow (probably, due to `FUSE`).

Wrappers like `Cryptomator` or `Boxcryptor` are virtually unusable under Ubuntu. They are simply garbage as for now. Even slower and buggy.

There is `odeke-em/drive`, but it doesn't seem to offer a possibility to simply mount and work with a file manager, like `FUSE` allows.

Gnome offers functionality to connect to a Google account, but it's probably not possible to use `encfs` with it (?).

What solution is good in terms of:

1. multi-platformity
2. speed
3. functionality (simple mount & sync)

Comment: The latest Cryptomator switched to FUSE by default on Linux, which should solve many of the issues it had previously. Maybe give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

If it supports your cloud of choice, [rclone](https://rclone.org/crypt/) can encrypt the files it uploads to the cloud. You can find details on this in the link, but the short version is:

1. Set up your remote.
2. Set up an encrypted remote with your "normal" remote as its backing storage.
3. Use the encrypted remote to store your files.

Going through rclone's interactive setup (`rclone config`) should make this very easy.

It supports the 3 major OSes and I've never had any problems with speed, but it *is* a terminal program which may or may not be ideal for you. There are a few GUIs for it, [RcloneBrowser](https://mmozeiko.github.io/RcloneBrowser/) comes to mind as a nice-looking cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Cryptomator](https://cryptomator.org/) as of version 1.3.2-0ppa2 works perfectly fine for me on my Ubuntu 16.04.4. I use it with Google Drive via [Insync Prime](https://www.insynchq.com/) which is not free, although it is well maintained and is affordable. Using Insync, I can asynchronously sync my selected Google Drive folders or my entire Google Drive. This asynchronous aspect of the syncing is evidently useful. As such, Cryptomator works fairly fast for me. I keep an eye on my Insync application "feed" to ensure it's working.